# Getting sum sub aggregation

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

I'd like to get the sum of a sub aggregation. For example, I have group by smartphones, group by carrier and then the average price for that carrier. I'd like to get the sum of all prices for all carriers for a specific smartphone. So essentially, I want something like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_smartphones": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "smartphone",
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        },
        "size": 200
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "price"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_carrier": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "carrier",
                "order": {
                  "group_by_avg": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "group_by_avg": {
                  "avg": {
                    "field": "price"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Except, when I do it like this I get this error:

> "type": "aggregation_initialization_exception",
>       "reason": "Aggregator [group_by_sum] of type [sum] cannot accept sub-aggregations"

How do I fix it so I can get the sum of all prices for each smartphone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there, actually the `sum` and `group_by_carrier` sub-aggregations both need to be at the same level:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_smartphones": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "smartphone",
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        },
        "size": 200
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_prices": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "group_by_carrier": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "carrier",
            "order": {
              "group_by_avg": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_avg": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You made my day! Thanks for introducing me sub-aggregations at the same level.

Comment: What if we have to calculate sum first and then do the average of that sum ?
e.g. 
i have values of profit from each branch
and i want to add it 
so that i can get daily profit of that bank
and then i want the monthly average of daily profit

Comment: @user4906240 feel free to create a new question to explain your need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534642/getting-avg-sub-aggregation